# Excel formula to convert hours into days

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet where I have a row of fields like so:

```
row  A      B
1    ID     Time
2    1      00:15:00
3    2      00:15:00
4    3      00:30:00
5    4      02:00:00
6    5      06:00:00

7    Total hours: 09:00:00 (using =SUM(B2:B6))
```

What I would like to do is to have one more field which shows converts the `Total hours` into `Total days` where one day is 8 hours. So if I have `Total hours: 09:00:00`, this would equal to 
`Total days: 2`. ([more info here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic))

I've tried the following function:

```
=MOD(HOUR(B7),8)
```

but the calculation is wrong - it gives me `6` instead of `2`.

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're not accidentally doing the mod of B6? And shouldn't the mod of MOD(9,8) be 1, not 2, anyway?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do, or why you think modular arithmetic is the way to do it. Do you mean =CEILING(HOUR(B7 / 8))? Modular arithmetic is for taking the remainder of a division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're taking the wrong approach and should be doing something like

```
=CEILING(TEXT(B7, "[h]")/8,1)
```

This should return 2, as it'll divide the hours by 8, and round up to 1 significant figure.

Comment: You're absolutely right! My approach was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: BTW Just in case somebody might need it - if your field contains a number > 24, `HOUR()` will return 0. The workaround to this is using `TEXT(B7, "[h]")` instead of `HOUR`.

Comment: @tftd Good point. Have amended the answer to reflect that